# Create ERD for Advantage Database Server 10

Tags: database-design, erd, advantage-database-server

I need to create an ERD for an ADS 10 database.
Reverese Engineering would be nice, since the database already exists.
Unfortunately, I didn't found a ERD-Tool which supports this database.

Does anybody knows a tool which supports this features?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Advantage Data Architect to get a model of a database.

As far as I know this only works on data dictionaries, but you can easily add free tables to a dictionary if necessary.

I don't know of any other ADS compatible modelling tools.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your information. The abilities for creating an ERD in the Data Architect are very rudimental and (in my opinion) useless for bigger dictionaries...

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth your while to take a look at [TOAD Data Modeler](http://www.casestudio.com/enu/products.aspx) by Quest Software.  TDM Version 2 officially supported ADS versions 8 and 9.  It looks like Version 3 (apparently the current version) dropped support for ADS and several other database products, although it may be that they simply have not tested version 3 with these products.

In any case, I took a few moments to download the Freeware version of TOAD 3, and installed the product with "Universal Database" support.  It was able to connect to my database through the Advantage OLE DB provider, and reverse engineer the table structure of a (very basic) Advantage data dictionary.

Maybe this meet your needs.