# Advantage Database ERD, from existing database.

Tags: sybase, erd, advantage-database-server, powerdesigner

Anyone aware of any tool which I can use to get ERD for existing advantage database? I am messing around with Advantage Data Architect but unable to find any option for ERD. I have also tried PowerDesigner but can't find Advantage Database option under DBMS.

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564184/create-erd-for-advantage-database-server-10

Comment: put this link as the answer so I can accept it Jens. I am using version 8.1 for advantage and the link you gave does tell me to use TOAD for version 8 which is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TOAD does it in my case. I am using advantage 8.1 so TOAD will support it.